# Wp E commerce product variation price from external csv file

Tags: ajax, wordpress

The e commerce  site I am working on needed the prices to be updated from a CSV file. the file has two fields : Price and SKU. On the product page I have inserted the following code so that the price is displayed according to the SKU. (It might look crude, but that is the my php level)

```
     <?php 
$mysku = wpsc_product_sku(wpsc_the_product_id());
  $data = 'path to the csv file.csv' ; //Obvious
    $pricelist = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($data, "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $pricelist[$data[3]] = $data[0];
        $pricecaption = "Price" ;
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }
    $myprice = $pricelist[$mysku]; 
    if (!$myprice == ' ') {
    echo " " ;
    }else {
    echo $pricecaption." : " .$myprice.".00" ; 
    }
  ?>
```

This replaces the prices on the product pages. The issue is with the single product page. There you have variations. So when you select a variation from the drop down, it just shows the price from the database.

I understood that the Ajax request is bringing the variation prices from the database. But I have no clue how to prevent that from happening and show the price according to the seleced variation's SKU.

Any help will be appreciated. I think the work has to be done on wpsc_update_product_price() function in ajax.functions.php

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to use to this hook: `add_action( 'wpsc_update_variation_product', 'yourFunction')` in your themes functions.php and edit the variations to manipulate the later steps of wpsc_update_product_price

But I don't understand why you cannot import the CSV to wpsc to use the original features of the shop...?

Comment: hmmm...
I didn't quiet get it. You mean the above code that I made had to be put as a function and called with add_action() in the function.php ? 

The CSV file is because they are a not for profit company and they don't have money to buy any plugins. Also there is no one who could update the entire product range. Since they generate pricelists for their physcial shop,  I thought I can utilise that to populate the prices.